# Sound cannot be played in android

Tags: javascript, android

Why sound cannot be played in android version 4.1? When in browser sound can be played very well.

i am trying to play the sound when the card match and when the card mismatch.

this is my code:

```
function checkPattern() { 
    if (isMatchPattern()) { 
        $(".card-flipped").removeClass("card-flipped").addClass("card-removed"); 
        if(document.webkitTransitionEnd){ 
            $(".card-removed").bind("webkitTransitionEnd",  removeTookCards); 
        }else{ 
            playAudio("mp3/WinLevel.mp3"); 
            removeTookCards(); 
        } 
    } else { 
        $(".card-flipped").removeClass("card-flipped"); 
        playAudio("mp3/WrongLose.mp3"); 
    } 
}
```

Did i missed anything?

Comment: Did you check the Speaker volume level ?

Answer (score 0):

To play a sound try this method:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(YourActivity.this, R.raw.mysound);
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        mp.release();
                    }
                });   
                mp.start();
```

This is the best way I found to play a sound in Android. Hope it helps!

Comment: The sound still cannot be played. Is there any other method?